# Dynamically created SVG not working in Firefox, but works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, svg

I am trying to figure out why this code of  is not working in Firefox. It's supposed to create horizontal paths, but I cannot see them in Firefox. Chrome and IE showing them properly. What could be the issue?

https://jsfiddle.net/7a6qm371/

```
<div>
<svg width="100%" height="500" id="svgBottomWall">
    <g style="stroke: aqua; fill: none;" id="svgBottomWallGridGroup"></g>
</svg>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var svgBottomWall = document.getElementById("svgBottomWall");
var rect = svgBottomWall.getBoundingClientRect();
var svgW = rect.width;



function createHorizontalLine(w, d) {
    var nline = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
    nline.setAttribute("d", "M 0 " + d + ", L " + w + " " + d);
    nline.setAttribute("stroke-width", 1);
    nline.setAttribute("stroke", "#ffffff");
    document.getElementById("svgBottomWallGridGroup").appendChild(nline);
}
for (var i = 0; i <= svgW; i = i + 100) {
    createHorizontalLine(svgW, i);
}
});
```

Comment: Seems to be that `svgBottomWall.clientWidth` as you have in your fiddle returns `0` in Firefox. I tried using a fixed value in the loop but it still doesn't work so that's just one of your problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `d` path parameters are incorrectly formatted.

You have something like

```
d="M 0 100, L 1000 100"
```

whereas it should be

```
d="M 0,100 L 1000,100"
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d

The fix is

```
nline.setAttribute("d", "M 0," + d + " L " + w + "," + d);
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7a6qm371/3/)</kbd>